# Django: Getting a list of meetings starting in a specific year and month when the start date is a Datetime object

Tags: python, django

I am making a web app in Python/Django and I am trying to make a calendar that displays meetings. I have the following in `models.py`.

```
class Meeting(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    admin = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    end_date = models.DateTimeField(default=None, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True)

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=70, null=True, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True)

class Member(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    meeting = models.ForeignKey(Meeting, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Essentially, a user and a meeting are linked in the Member model. I have the following function in `database.py`, which creates a new Meeting:

```
def createMeeting(name, location, admin, start_date, end_date, description):
    new = Meeting(name=name, location=location, admin=admin, start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, description=description)
    if not duplicate(Meeting, new):
        new.save()

    membership = Member(user=admin, meeting=new)
    if not duplicate(Member, membership):
        membership.save()
```

I am trying to get a list of all the meetings that a logged in user is in that are in a particular month and year. However, since the a meeting's start_date is a DateTime object, I am not sure what is the best way to do this. Any insights are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with the [**`__year`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year) and the [**`__month`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#month) on the `start_date` field:

```
Meeting.objects.filter(
    start_date__year=2019,
    start_date__month=11,
    member__user=request.user
)
```

Of course `2019` and `11` can be a different year and month.